# how to access a website in my browser from an external network

Tags: google-chrome, networking, safari

I am having trouble following the only tutorial I could find on the certain type of port forwarding I think I need. The website I need to bring up isn't available for a direct access from outside networks. I need to know how to get into a computer that is accessible from the outside and then get into the one that is only available in the network that is external to mine. Any ideas on how I can use my browser to access those websites that are in the external network?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a ping to your web site, check that your site is open for connection from outside networks and nothing blocking port 80.

Comment: It isn't available for a direct access from outside networks. The idea is to get into a computer that is accessible from the outside and then get into the one that is only available in the network that is external to mine. I need to bring up the webpage from the computer that is only accessible in the network external to mine.

Comment: I still did not get you clearly.. Do we speak about 3 pcs? First is yours, second is pc that you can access from outside and third pc is with web page that you want to get from second pc ? If yes you can install RDP on second pc in case it is windows or vnc if it is linux. And once you have access to second pc - you can browse to the web page on third pc.

Comment: This is the correct interpretation. I was seeing if there was another way than using a vnc, but if this is the only way then I will note this for future use. Is this the only way of doing it?

Comment: You can install team veiwer on your and second pc

Comment: Or you can set static routes on  your routers.